# Can't "capture more environment data" in the Azure spatial anchors basic demo

Tags: c#, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm currently adding Azure spatial anchors to my app.
So I've decided to start with the demo provided [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples).

I just set my Account ID and my Azure spatial anchors ressource primary key in the "Azure spatial anchors demo wrapper" and that's all.

Then I build the scene. Next I've made a x86 Release and deploy on my device.
When I start the demo I can Air tap but when I arrive on the step "Move your device to capture more environment data: 0%" the 0% value doesn't increase and I'm blocked at this step even if I'm Air tapping.

Did I do something wrong ?

Note that I've just freshly cloned the git project and open the Unity folder in Unity. Added my Account ID and Ressource Key, build and deploy in release x86 on my device. The app is starting well but can't capture environment data.

Thank you for your help.

---

Unity version : 2018.3.8f

Visual studio 2017 v15.9.7

Hololens with developer mode enabled and up to date (Windows 10 october 2018 included).

---

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by enabling
`SpatialPerception` in `playersetting -> capabilities`